# Converting this class to a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code and wanting to convert this as a functional component using hooks if possible. I know that hooks seem to be what react is moving towards. So, I want to make sure I work more with functional components than classes to manage state.

```
import React from 'react';
 
import AuthUserContext from './context';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
 
const withAuthentication = Component => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
 
      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };
    }
 
    componentDidMount() {
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          authUser
            ? this.setState({ authUser })
            : this.setState({ authUser: null });
        },
      );
    }
 
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    }
 
    render() {
      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }
 
  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};
 
export default withAuthentication;
```

Here is what I tried, not sure how to get around the Component tag piece.

```
const withAuthentication = (Component) => {


const WithAuthentication = (props) => {
    
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);
 
    useEffect(() => {
      this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          authUser
            ? setAuthUser(true)
            : setAuthUser(null);
        })
    }, [authUser]);
 
    return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
        <Component {...this.props} />
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
 
  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};
```

Comment: If you provide the code snippets that you tried to do that shows your effort in trying to solve this then you would be more likely to receive help. As now we're not sure whether you even tried to attempt this.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I edit my post with what I tried. The component piece is what part that Im confused on how to switch over from the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 things that need to be tweaked, from what I can see:

- In the functional component, `props` is an *argument* - a standalone variable, not a property of `this`. So change `this.props.firebase` to `props.firebase`. Similarly, `<Component {...this.props} />` should be `<Component {...props} />`.
- The class component does `this.setState({ authUser })`, but the functional component does `setAuthUser(true)`. You probably want to do `setAuthUser(authUser)` instead if truthy.
- The `onAuthStateChanged` should only run when the component mounts, per the `componentDidMount`. So the dependency array in `useEffect` should be empty, rather than running every time `authUser` runs. (`[authUser]` should be `[]`)
- The `componentWillUnmount` section is not translated into the functional component. Return a callback from the `useEffect` to run it when cleaning up the component, which looks to be the return value of `onAuthStateChanged`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
    authUserResponse => {
      setAuthUser(authUserResponse || null);
    }
  );
}, []);
```

The immediate return from `useEffect` might be a bit confusing - it's equivalent to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
    authUserResponse => {
      setAuthUser(authUserResponse || null);
    }
  );
  return listener; // run listener function when component unmounts
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarity on the unmount working with return. I never learned that from videos I've watched.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `props` parameter and use the `authUser` itself at `setAuthUser(authUser)`.

For the `componentWillUnmount` logic you can remove it as it seems useless.

```
const withAuthentication = (Component) => {

const WithAuthentication = (props) => {
    
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);
 
    useEffect(() => {
     props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          authUser
            ? setAuthUser(authUser)
            : setAuthUser(null);
        })
    }, [authUser]);
  
    return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
        <Component {...this.props} />
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
 
  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};
```